# Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8

Tags: 12.10, windows-8, installation

1) I tried the methods given in the forum without much luck. I have a Sony Vaio Windows 8 -preinstalled laptop. I downloaded ubuntu and copied it to flash drive and tried to reboot - I get a message the flash drive is empty - when the flash drive clearly has Ubuntu.

2)The other problem is I had earlier tried to install using Windows installer, I got an error message but the screen goes back to a page offering me the choice of the operating system between Ubuntu and Windows 8. When I click Ubuntu I get the error message again re the missing boot file.

I would appreciate some help

Comment: Have you created bootable flash drive? If yes, what program have you used for it? And what is displaying you message that the flash drive is empty?

Answer (score 0):

try taking the ubuntu iso file and burning it to a cd or make a bootable iso mounted to a flash drive. if you jist copy over the files then it is not bootable. the easiest way to do it is to burn to usb, then boot from there

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this recently with a Sony Vaio T13 with Windows 8 preinstalled, in principle it should be possible to do a dual boot with Ubuntu 12.10 64bit which knows all about UEFI and SecureBoot but I couldn't get it to work. Instead I installed Ubuntu into a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) virtual machine which was a much easier operation, description [here](http://www.ianhopkinson.org.uk/2013/01/windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-a-sony-vaio-t13-laptop/).

I believe you can expect a performance hit of about 10% for running in a virtual machine but I was happy to accept that.